# After npm run build I got blank page VueJS

Tags: vue.js

After running the 'npm run build' command, I encounter a blank screen. In my Vue project, I edited the vue.config.js file as follows:

module.exports = {
publicPath: ''
}

It outputs 'file:///signin' and I suspect it's unable to redirect properly.

It doesn't open. How can I fix this issue? Additionally, besides the images I provided, is there anything else I need to check? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKOEA.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVds2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKumg.png)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . "It outputs 'file:///signin' " - outputs where? It looks like you just opened index.html in s browser. You said how you build the app but not how you run it. You need a webserver configured for SPA to make the router to work correctly